# python - dynamic import

Tags: python, dynamic, python-import

How can I accomplish something like this in python 2?

```
my_variable = something1
imported = False

try:
  import my_variable #something1.py, something2.py, etc... I think I can use __import__(my_variable)
  imported = True
except ImportError:
  print('Error importing ' + my_variable + '.py')

if imported:
  my_variable.function() #where my_variable actually is something1 ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are on Python 2.7 or higher, you can use [importlib](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/importlib.html):

```
import importlib

module_name = 'sys'

try:
    sys = importlib.import_module(module_name, package = None)
except Exception:
    print('Error importing:', module_name)

if module_name in locals():
    print(sys.argv)
```